# carousel timeline causing "jumps" on every slide

Tags: javascript, jquery, carousel

**1st problem**
On https://bm-translations.de/#sprachrichtungen you can see the website "jumps" a few pixel towards the top on every slide of this autosliding timeline. I thinks its caused because of the `#0` which is added to every point of the timeline to make it slide. But I am not sure how to make it work without jumping?

As its quite a lot code I created a pen so you can see:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gxxWOM

**2nd problem:** 
When its autosliding for example to year 2000 and then I press manually 2016. If its then autosliding again its not going to 2017 as it should but to the next after 2000, which could be annoying for the user. How to adjust this code?

```
//adjustment > Autoslide

function timeLineAutoPlay(){
var current = 0;
setInterval(function(){
        current ++;
        $($('.events a')[current]).trigger('click');
        if((current +1)%4 == 0)
        $('.next').trigger('click');
        if(current > $('.events a').length) {
          current = 0;
          $('.prev').trigger('click');
          $('.prev').trigger('click');
        }
},7000);
}    
timeLineAutoPlay();
```